# Navigating a nested array using arrows

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to navigate the up / down arrows on my keyboard through the children of an array, but I don't understand how I can refer specifically to the children.

Array:

```
options: [
                {name: 'Выход детали из строя в процессе эксплуатации', value: null,
                    children: [{name: 'Увеличение зазора, люфт (дробь/стуки)', value: 53},
                                {name: 'Обрыв детали', value: 54}]},

                {name: 'Поломка при установке', value: null},

                {name: 'Брак до установки', value: null,
                    children: [{name: 'Недокомплект', value: 55},
                                {name: 'Заводской брак (замятия, отсутствие резьбы, пробой пыльника и т.д.)',
                                    value: 56}]},

     ],
```

List output:

```
<div v-if="areOptionsVisible"
     :style="{maxHeight: maxHeight, overflow: 'auto', zIndex: zIndex}"
     class="w-autocomplete__items">
    <div v-for="option in filteredOptions" class="w-autocomplete__item_first" >
        {{ option.name }}

            <div v-for="item in option.children" class="w-autocomplete__item"
                :class="{'w-autocomplete__item_active': currentIndex === item}"
                @mouseenter="setActive(item)"
                 @keyup.up="changeCurrent('up', item)"
                 @keyup.down="changeCurrent('down', item)"
                 @click="doChoose(item)">
                {{ item.name }}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Methods:

```
    computed: {
        filteredOptions(){
            if (this.searchText === ''){
                return this.options;
            } else{
               return this.options.flatMap(option => {
                   return option.children;
                }).filter(elem => {
                return elem && elem.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText.toLowerCase());
             });
            }
        },
    },

    methods: {
        setActive(index) {
            this.currentIndex = index;
        },
        changeCurrent(direction) {


            if (this.currentIndex === null) {
                this.currentIndex = 0;
            } else if (direction === 'up') {
                if (this.currentIndex - 1 >= 0) {
                    this.currentIndex -= 1;
                }
            } else if (direction === 'down') {
                if (this.currentIndex + 1 <= this.options.length - 1) {
                    this.currentIndex += 1;
                }
            }
        },
        doChoose(item) {
            this.chosenItem = this.currentIndex;
            this.areOptionsVisible = false;
            this.searchText = item.name;
        },
               
    },
```

`currentIndex` now is an object, each specific child on hover. I want to move with the arrows in the same way as on hover, excluding the top-level elements. Please tell me how to do this?

[image: graphical view:]

Comment: Please show some graphical view of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If item is the option that should be selected then why not to just assign it? like `changeCurrent(direction, item) { this.currentIndex = item}`

Answer (score 0):

`currentIndex` is an `Object` because you've set it to `item`, which is an `Object`.

If you want to set `currentIndex` to the item's array index, `v-for` supports a second argument that provides the item index:

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<!-- <div v-for="item in option.children"> -->

<div v-for="(item, index) in option.children">
```